# Не могу реализовать функцию

Tags: c++

Я создаю такую функцию

```
void GetDirectory(char disk)    
{
    using namespace std;

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW wfd;

    HANDLE const hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"C:\\*", &wfd);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)
    {
        do
        {
            std::wcout << &wfd.cFileName[0] << std::endl;
        } while (NULL != FindNextFileW(hFind, &wfd));

        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

Она выводит список файлов/папок на диске C:

```
int main()
{

    GetDirectory();
    return 0;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы я к примеру в функции(GetDirectory()) передавал букву логического диска, а он искал там?

Comment: Ну так сделайте из переданной буквы путь - ваше `C:\\*`, где вместо `C` - буква диска...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот так, но вам будет  проще сделать это со строкой `stl`.

```
void GetDirectory(char disk)    
{
    wchar_t buffer[12] = {};
    if(swprintf(buffer, L"%c:\\*", disk) == 0) return;

    using namespace std;

    WIN32_FIND_DATAW wfd;

    HANDLE const hFind = FindFirstFileW(buffer, &wfd);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)
    {
        do
        {
            std::wcout << &wfd.cFileName[0] << std::endl;
        } while (NULL != FindNextFileW(hFind, &wfd));

        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня C2665 ошибка

Comment: Подправил: `if(swprintf(buffer, L"%c:\\", disk) == 0) return;`

Comment: А как это вы собрались писать в константную строку? :) Уберите `const` в объявлении `buffer`.

Comment: Да, и ещё нужно 4 бек слеша

Comment: Во-первых, почему вдруг "нужно 4 бекслеша"? Во-вторых, куда пропала `*`? Документация на `FindFirstFileW` ясно говорит, что эта строка не должна заканчиваться на `\\`.

Comment: @AnT, перепутал с URL